# How to see the columns added to the table programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have created a database named test.sqlite .In that I have added a table named coffee and I am adding columns to it programmatically and when I run my program it executes successfully. But I want to see in the sqlite command prompt the columns that I have added programmatically. How is it possible? And what is the command to see the no of tables in the database in sqlite command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sqlite_master table to get a list of all the objects in the database (table, views, indexes, etc.):

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;
```

Use the pragma to get the list of columns for a table:

```
PRAGMA table_info('TableName');
```

Comment: i entered this command in the terminal but it does not produced any results.

Comment: They work fine at the sqlite command prompt for me.  Be sure to include the semicolons after the commands.  And for the PRAGMA, of course replace 'TableName' with the actual name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window, navigate to the directory containing test.sqlite, and at the command line, type:

yourname$ **sqlite3 test.sqlite**

SQLite will start up and give you a command prompt at which you can type the **.dump** command to see the entire structure of the database:

sqlite> **.dump**

You can also use the **.help** command to find other ways to look at your data. Or, read the man page for **sqlite3**.